# Scatter plot in python

Tags: python, scatter

I have a vector X of size 100x2 and the corresponding binary labels in a vector y ={1, -1} of length 100. I would like to plot the scattered data with s.t. I get the features on the axis and the color of the data point corresponds to a label e.g. red is -1, yellow is 1 for a given data point.

I've been looking into matplotlib and the fcn scatter however it accepts only a single feature vector and its label.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using `seaborn` (or matplotlib as well). Below is the code.

1. I am creating a random array of size 100x2 and calling it X. I am creating a random array of 0s and 1s of size 100x1 and calling it Y

```
>> import numpy as np
>> X = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 2))
>> Y = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100))
>> X
   array([[11, 47],
       [23,  2],
       [91, 14],
       [65, 32],
       [81, 78],
       ....
>> Y
   array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Use Seaborn scatterplot

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x=X[:,0], y=X[:,1], hue=Y)
```

**Output sns scatterplot**

[image]